# Use of "don't mention it" for "you're welcome"?

Tags: phrases

In which American regions is "don't mention it" used for "you're welcome"?

Comment: The vast majority. It means that so little effort was expended it's not notable or even worthy of expressed gratitude. "It's nothing!"

Comment: This sort of response isn't unique to English. The Spanish "no hay de que" or "de nada" , for example. "There is nothing you need to thank me for." (Personally, I prefer to respond with "[it wzs] my pleasure".)

Comment: There are also *no worries*, *no problem* and *it was nothing*. These are all used in the UK too.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the US, but I know that is is often used in the UK and Australia. Sorry I couldn't help out more.

After some research [which may or may not be correct] it seems as though is directly translates from french. Also it is commonly used by black teens/young people. Which I can guess would probably means the south, and makes sense when considering France's influence on New Orleans and the surrounding region.

Hopefully this will send you in the right direction.

Comment: My impression is that French made a large impact on language in New Orleans and Louisiana, but very little for most of the South.

Comment: I can tell you I don't hear it in the West. In California you might hear "no problem" or "no biggie" (short for no big deal)

Comment: @BrianHitchcock - it's known and used in CA too, just amongst a different demographic (old people, like me). I ran some interesting Ngram queries, seems 'don't mention it' was dominant until approx. late 19th C when 'no problem' became more prevalent; Whereas 'no biggie' flat-lines. Check it out @ https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=don't+mention+it%2Cno+problem%2Cno+biggie&year_start=1800&year_end=1904&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdo%20not%20mention%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cno%20problem%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cno%20biggie%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Son of a gun.  I sorta figured it was more old-fashioned. I myself am no spring chicken, but I was reared on the shores of Puget Sound, and have been in SoCal only since 2004. Guess I'd better get to know some more old Californians. Should be easy; I'm in a seniors-only condo complex.  By the way, no way to tell how many of those usages in ngram were actually in lieu of "you're welcome".

Comment: But I see that in entire 20th century "don't mention it" virtually flatlines (not at zero, but at its 1900 level) So it's apparently alive and well, neither growing nor shrinking, but now a small fraction compated to the fast-growing "no problem".  But I suspect that "no problem" is more likely used in other contexts:  "Can you fix this?" "No problem!"

Comment: @BrianHitchcock - yah, you're right, no telling. 'Don't mention it' struck me as a fairly common response among those who were rather literate and polite--i.e., well-spoken--even though it's colloquial--whereas 'no problem' was more hip, street idiom. I was kinda surprised to see how much currency 'DMI' has lost and for how long. It's downright antiquarian!. I've spent some years in both PugetSd & SoCal but I'm a NE fan.

Comment: Minor gripe: It doesn't make sense to distinguish between Black teens and young people.